# In PingFederate, is there an API to query a list of users and a list of groups?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, pingfederate

I can use OpenAM to query a list of users and a list of groups by using its REST API:

```
/openam/json/users?_queryID=*
/openam/json/groups?_queryID=*
```

Is there an equivalent (or similar) API of the above in PingFederate?

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that is currently available in the product. The reason being that it can use any of a number of user stores (adapters in the product's terminology) at the same time,  and it doesn't have a specific set of users.

If you are a current customer, you could request it.