# How to query PingFederate

Tags: pingfederate

I am new to Ping Federate and have a few questions.  I am trying to understand from an architect's perspective a number of things around querying and APIs.  I understand Ping Federate supports attribute-query request.  This seems very much doable but only appears to work for querying additional attributes based on the current SAML instance.

What I am trying to understand is what options exist for querying a 'user list' or querying attributes for specific users?  I need to check users for changes in specific attributes or have a means to be notified of changes to specific attributes.  Based on the following somewhat related link, I believe it is not possible:

[In PingFederate, is there an API to query a list of users and a list of groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692571/in-pingfederate-is-there-an-api-to-query-a-list-of-users-and-a-list-of-groups)

But, I would think architecturally something like this should be possible. Is there a way to query PingFederate in the manner above?  Or have it notify you of changes?  Directly or indirectly?

Regards...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attribute Query is not restricted to an ongoing user session if that's what you're worried about.

See here http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF72/SP+Services#SPServices-1110907 for the endpoint that a PingFederate **SP** would use to execute an attribute query to a partner SAML IDP. The latter IDP may use PingFederate as an IDP (which I believe is what you're looking for) or any other SAML implementation that supports SAML Attribute Query.

Wrt. notifications: PingFederate implements the SCIM (http://www.simplecloud.info/) protocol for this purpose (http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF72/Configuring+Outbound+Provisioning) so you could use that to get notifications.